# Compare hours and minutes

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am developing an app based on date and time in java. In this app, my user is allowed to record an video only once per hour. so for this I am storing the previous time has used my app.

So when the user starts my app for the next time, I am comparing the time and if the time interval is more than one hour I must allow my user to record, else I should not allow. How to compare hours and minutes efficiently in java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the system time with

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and compare the new time with the old one. One hour means a difference of 1000 * 60 * 60 milliseconds

Comment: +1: I prefer to write `60 * 60 * 1000`. or `3600 * 1000` ;)  Note: this is not affected by daylight savings changes.

Answer (score 7):

From [@Dalino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948543/compare-hours-and-minutes/5948594#5948594) answer, you may use `TimeUnit` enum class for time conversions.

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long lastVisit =  ...; // in milliseconds
if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now - lastVisit) > 0) {
    // allow
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just store the time when they exit (or whatever) and then on start up, read the time, add an hour to it, and compare with the current time?

You don't need to compare the actual hours and minutes - just the duration of time between then and now.

Personally I'd suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for all Java date/time work, but in this case you could just use `Date`, and add an hour's-worth of milliseconds. Note that you should definitely store a UTC date/time instead of a local one, as otherwise daylight saving changes etc will mess things up.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Joda [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html): have a look [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff)

Comment: +0: I would call that The Over Kill 9000 Plus Extreme ;)